# JQuery Ajax form submitting

Tags: .net, javascript, jquery, ajax

Not exactly sure why this is happening, but upon click of a button I call a JQuery Ajax control, after that I do not want to continue submitting the form, but before the page gets still submitted.

```
<asp:ImageButton id="btnContinue" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

and the jQuery:

```
            $("#<%=btnContinue.ClientID%>").click(function() {
            var currentpickupLocation = document.getElementById("<%=ddlPickupLocation.ClientID %>").value;
            var currentpickupDate = document.getElementById("<%=txtPickupDate.ClientID %>").value;
            var currentCulture = "<%= GetCulture() %>";
            var params = $.toJSON({pickupLocation: currentpickupLocation, pickupDate: currentpickupDate});
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "LocationService.asmx/GetBlackoutDates",
                data: params,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(locations) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a return false in the click area like so:

```
$("#<%=btnContinue.ClientID%>").click(function() {
    var currentpickupLocation = document.getElementById("<%=ddlPickupLocation.ClientID %>").value;
    var currentpickupDate = document.getElementById("<%=txtPickupDate.ClientID %>").value;
    var currentCulture = "<%= GetCulture() %>";
    var params = $.toJSON({
        pickupLocation: currentpickupLocation, 
        pickupDate    : currentpickupDate
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "LocationService.asmx/GetBlackoutDates",
        data: params,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(locations) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;  //this tells the browser not to submit
});
```

Comment: No worries, ran into this like a year ago, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Using preventDefault() works as well:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29